# Setting UISearch in navigation bar in ios7

Tags: uisearchbar, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

I'm having a search bar in my navigation bar using

```
[self.searchDisplayController setDisplaysSearchBarInNavigationBar:YES];
```

It displays a search results view when the search bar is tapped but there is no cancel button in the search results view.Can u please give me suggestion for doing it programmatically

I have to do it programmatically.

Plz anybody give me a hand.

Thankz in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES]
```

I'm using something like this myself (implementing UISearchDisplayDelegate):

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
  [controller.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I have tried the above code but its not working. setShowsCancelButton is not the method of UISearchDisplayController .It is for UISearchBar. Eventhough i tried to use

[self.searchDisplayController.searchbar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES]

But its not displaying Cancel button in search results view

Comment: Of course you're right, I updated my sample so it calls the method on UISearchBar now.

Are you sure that the UISearchBar instance you are calling this method on is the same one that's embedded in your navigation bar ?

Comment: By implementing the above code in delegate its working.Thanks you buddy:)